# Elements of order $10$ in $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_{10}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> How many elements in the group $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_{10}$ are of order $10$?

I think the easiest way to answer this question might be to write them out, but I'm not sure how to write them out.

Comment: Do you know what $A\times B$ means?

Comment: No. I do not think that I have a clear understanding of A x B.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted in a comment, the order of a group means one thing, and the order of an element means entirely another.

If $(A,\circ_A)$ and $(B,\circ_B)$ are groups, then the direct product $(A,\circ_A)\times(B,\circ_B)$ (often written just $A\times B$) is defined as the group $(A\times B,\circ)$, where $(a_1,b_1)\circ(a_2,b_2)=(a_1\circ_A a_2,b_1\circ_B b_2)$.

So $(a,b)^n=e=(e_A,e_B)$ iff $a^n=e_A$ and $b^n=e_B$.

This happens iff $|a|\mid n$ and $|b|\mid n$, which of course is precisely when $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\mid n$.

Thus $|(a,b)|=\operatorname{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$.

Comment: Thanks for this definition. I'm having trouble understanding something though. I have written out the elements of Z2 x Z10 as such {(0,0),(0,1)...(0,8),(0,9), (1,0),(1,1)...(1,8),(1,9)}. When I consider the element (0,2) the order of 0 is 1 and the order of 2 is 5 which both divide 10. Does that mean that the element (0,2) has order 10? Because I think this element should have order 5. What am I missing?

Comment: @Cindy, $1$ and $5$ both divide $10$ (so $10$ is a multiple of $1$ and $5$), but $10$ is not the *least* such number! $\operatorname {lcm}(1,5)=5\mid 10$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: how many elements of ${\mathbb Z}_{10}$ have order 10? For such an element $a$, $(0,a) \in {\mathbb Z}_2 \times {\mathbb Z}_{10}$ also has order 10.

Hint 2: what is the order of $1$ in ${\mathbb Z}_2$? When is an element $(1,a) \in {\mathbb Z}_2 \times {\mathbb Z}_{10}$ of order 10?

Comment: I guess I don't know how to figure out order. It's confusing because sometimes the "order" means the number of elements, and sometimes "order" means n when a^n=identity. How do I figure out the order of an element in Z10?

Comment: Thanks @Magdiragdag. I think I am figuring this out.
Hint 1: 4 elements in Z10 have order 10. They are 1,3,7,9.
Hint 2: The order of 1 in Z2 is 2. An element (1,a) in Z2 x Z10 has order 10 when a has order 5 (right?).
So, the number of elements in Z2 x Z10 that have order 10 is 12?

Comment: I think we are defining Z10 differently. I'm using D10=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9). In this case, I think that 1 does have order 10. If I defined D10 as (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) then 1 would have order 1. Right?

Comment: @Cindy you're sort-of right; I temporarily got confused with the ${\mathbb Z}_{10}^*$, in which the operation is multiplication.